# Carousel; explanation of a certain phenomenon.

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, everyday-life, centrifugal-force

There are countless of hilarious youtube videos like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pegHuqSHCRg) one here, in which you can see that the carousel causes people to be pulled outwards.

- What force is actually working on them, and why does it pull them outwards (instead of for example inwards)?
- Can you give me some other (notable) example of this force in everyday life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the [centrifugal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force).  An object that's in motion (with velocity in a certain direction) will tend to remain in motion in that direction (Newton's [first law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion)).  If the object is tethered to a stationary point (by a rope, say), the tension of the rope continuously changes the direction of the object's velocity, which creates circular motion. It also creates a "force" exerted on the object, since the object "wants" to continue moving in a straight line ([inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia)), but the rope is causing it to change its direction.  If the rope breaks, the object would fly off tangentially to the last point when the rope was intact.

On a carousel, a person's arms holding on to the railings represents the "rope". When this connection breaks, the person will fly off tangentially to the carousel.

Other notable examples include:

- Planetary orbits... the centrifugal force on the planets is balanced out by the sun's gravity.
- Clay on a pottery wheel... if you spin the wheel too fast, the clay will fly off.
- A centrifuge in a laboratory.

Comment: You mean centripetal force here "Planetary orbits... the centrifugal force on the planets is balanced out by the sun's gravity."

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *[centrifugal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force)*. It's not an actual force though, rather, it's an apparent force.

For example, if a person X is on a rotating platform (such as the one in the video) that rotates at a constant angular speed, an external viewer will see X do a uniform movement. But X, while seeing himself as immobile in the carousel, will perceive a force that drags him out (the centrifugal force) that pulls him away from the center of the carousel, which is balanced by the *constraint reaction* (not sure how it translates into English). Anyway, the only actual force here is this last one, the other one is apparent.

In any case, this is really a basic explanation and if someone can help me improve it, it'd be great.

An example in real life is when you enter a bend while inside the car. If you turn right, the centrifugal force will pull you (the body) to the left. Again: the force doesn't exist, it's only apparent.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is there anything wrong stated?

Answer (score 1):

It's called the sudden **absense** of **[Centripetal Force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force)**

Newton's [first law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) says that a person falling out of a carousel will continue to move in a straight line (i.e. tangential to carousel rotation) until some other force is applied (friction with asphelt, impact with wall).

Answer (score -2):

Carousel: Centripetal Force
Since the ball is traveling in a circular path, an outside force must be acting on the ball – that force is the string. The string is pulling the ball back toward you, acting as the centripetal force. Centripetal means 'center-seeking' and is the force that is acting on the carousel.